# Pandas to_excel doesnt write line breaks

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read an Excel and writing the data in a new Excel with a new column.

Here is a Sample Excel `module`: Please ignore the table formatting

```
+-------+------+------+
| Col1  | Col2 | Col3 |
+-------+------+------+
| Prod1 | "ABC |  100 |
           XYZ"         
| Prod2 | Test |  200 |
+-------+------+------+
```

I read this excel and add a new column in dataframe by :

```
df = pd.read_excel(module)
df["Status"] = ""
```

I add a value in new column by :

```
rowIndex = df.index[df['Col1'] == 'Prod1'].tolist()
df.loc[rowIndex, 'Status'] = 'Yes'
```

I write this `df` in a new excel by:

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index = None, header=True)
```

But in New excel data looks like :

```
+-------+----------+------+-------+
| Col1  | Col2     | Col3 | Status|
+-------+----------+------+-------+
| Prod1 | "ABCXYZ" |  100 | Yes   |

| Prod2 | Test     |  200 |       |
+-------+----------+------+-------+
```

As you can see that `"ABCXYZ"` comes in one line. I want it to be in multiple line as it was in old excel. What changes I can do in code to retain this formatting while writing data in a new excel?

P.S : While debugging I found that `df` has value as `"ABC\nXYZ"` but it still writes in a single line.

Comment: What happens if you change merge_cells to False. df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index = None, header=True, merge_cells=False)

Comment: _While debugging I found that..._ Yes, this is a matter of formatting in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I found below python library which helped me achieving formatting :

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler, utils

StyleFrame(df, styler_obj=Styler(horizontal_alignment=utils.horizontal_alignments.left, font = utils.fonts.calibri)).to_excel("output4.xlsx", index = None, header=True).save()
```